# Как запустить.js файл?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как запустить .js файл(программу, написанную на javascript)?

Comment: А как запустить — для начала спросить у автора программы, в какой именно среде он предусмотрел её запуск

Comment: Программу писал я сам(обычная змейка). Раньше запускал через html, на сайте, но теперь хочу пересобрать в .jar, может быть, или что-то в таком роде и запускать как приложение

Comment: Значит запускать только на сайте. Javascript не имеет к jar-файлам никакого отношения

Comment: Других вариантов нет?

Comment: Зачем именно jar? И на каком устройстве хотите запустить программу?

Comment: @DiD: _"Зачем именно jar?"_ Видимо потому, что Java == JavaScript :)

Comment: На пк. Можно как угодно, но главное запустить и желательно не в браузере

Comment: Возможно, electron?

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему, вы не до конца понимаете область применения языка JavaScript и его отличия от Java. Более опытные товарищи уже успели посмеяться над вами в коментах выше - расшифрую.

1. Javascript не имеет никакого отношения к Java (название было выбрано в маркетинговых целях). Таким образом, вы никак не сможете конвертировать ваш скрипт на JS в JAR-файл. Разве что вручную перепишите ваш код на Java.
2. Основными средами выполнения JS являются браузеры и Node.js. С браузером вы уже знакомы - там JS используется для создания интерактива на страницах - фронтэнд разработка. Node.js используется для написания движков сайтов - бекэнд разработка. Так же, в качестве виртуальной машины для запуска системных скриптов - но реже. Судя по всему, раз ваша змейка запускалась на сайте, она реализована как фронтэнд-скрипт. Я не специалист по JS, но про запуск фронтенд-скриптов отдельно от браузера я не слышал. Компромиссным вариантов может быть запуск скрипта на **Electron** - это такой браузерный движок, для создания десктопных приложений с помощью html + css + javascript. Думаю вам нужен именно он.